# simple_form custom layout for radio buttons

Tags: radio-button, simple-form

how the heck do you make a custom layout for radio buttons insimple_form?

this code generates a vertical list of radio buttons:

```
%fieldset
  = f.input :my_collection, label: false, collection: MY_COLLECTION, as: :radio_buttons
```

but what i want, is for the radio buttons to be in separate columns. so i've output the literal radio buttons like:

```
.control-group.radio_buttons.required.my_collection
    .controls
      .row-fluid
        .span3
          %label.radio
            = f.radio_button :my_collection, 'Foo', class: "radio-buttons required"
            Foo
          %label.radio
            = f.radio_button :my_collection, 'Bar', class: "radio-buttons required"
            Bar
        .span3
          %label.radio
            = f.radio_button :my_collection, 'Biz', class: "radio-buttons required"
            Biz
          %label.radio
            = f.radio_button :my_collection, 'Baz', class: "radio-buttons required"
            Baz
```

---

**seems to render OK, but the validations stop working. any ideas?**

Comment: Please be more specific, what is the validation rule? What is the error message after the change you mentioned in your question?

Comment: thanks, sorry but i can't even remember the situation. just wound up hardcoding the html form examining previously successful output. then later started using the `do` block

Answer (score -1):

Check the [custom wrappers](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers) docs. There are some examples with Boostrap or others frameworks.

For instance, you can add this in an simple_form initializer to create a custom checkbox wrapper:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|

  config.wrappers :inline_checkbox, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_input, :wrap_with => { :class => 'checkbox inline' }
      ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
    end
  end
end
```

then use it like any other input but specifying the custom wrapper (Slim code):

```
= f.input :remember_me, wrapper: :inline_checkbox
```